# inplace quick sort implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement the inplace quick sort as explained in the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Below is the python code, The partition function does not work as expected.

```
def swap(array, index1, index2):
    tmp = array[index1]
    array[index1] = array[index2]
    array[index2] = tmp

def partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex):
    pivotValue = array[pivotIndex]
    swap(array, pivotIndex, right)
    storeIndex = left
    for i in range(left, right - 1):
        if array[i] < pivotValue:
            swap(array, i, storeIndex)
            storeIndex = storeIndex + 1
            print array, i
    swap(array, storeIndex, right)
    return storeIndex

def quicksort(array, left ,right):
    if right > left:
        print left, right
        pivotIndex = left
        pivotNewIndex = partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex)
        quicksort(array, left, pivotNewIndex - 1)
        quicksort(array, pivotNewIndex + 1, right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [3,7,8,5,2,1,9,5,4]
    partition(array, 0, len(array) - 1, 3) # 5 is pivot
    print array # expecting all the elements to the left of pivot value(5) will be lesser or equal.
```

Comment: "does not work as expected" -- What is expected?  What does it do instead?  Try to be specific.  Sometimes in figuring these things out, it makes the answer clear to you.

Comment: You need to explain how you expect it to work and how that's different from what you're actually seeing.

Comment: You're using `range` function in a wrong way, fix it (Maxim Skurydin's answer is right). But generally you can write this code more pythonic, Look at these examples of quicksort in python: http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Python)

Comment: I've got a working Quicksort in Pure Python and Cython available here: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make at least 2 fixes:

```
def partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex):
    pivotValue = array[pivotIndex]
    swap(array, pivotIndex, right)
    storeIndex = left
    for i in range(left, right):    # range doesn't include right element already
        if array[i] <= pivotValue:  # need to check for equality (not really necessary for the sorting routine)
            swap(array, i, storeIndex)
            storeIndex = storeIndex + 1
            print array, i
    swap(array, storeIndex, right)
    return storeIndex
```

`range(left, right)` returns a list of items like this `[left, left + 1, ..., right - 1]`, so there is no need to do generate a list with `range(left, right -1)`, because thus we shall skip not only the last element of the list (where pivot is), but also the one before last (i.e. `right - 2`).

If it is expected that after `partition` the elements on left from pivot should be less than or *equal*, we should reflect it in the comparison during the array traversal (`array[i] <= pivotValue`).

Comment: I don't think the check for equality is required, is it?

Comment: That is correct, it shouldn't affect the overall sorting algorithm. However, the OP mentions in the comment that he expects that `all the elements to the left of pivot value(5) will be lesser or equal.`

Answer (score 0):

is it not better way using less variables and clean approach

#!/usr/bin/python

```
Array = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,23,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,412,2,4]

def swap(a,i,j):
    temp=a[i]
    a[i]=a[j]
    a[j]=temp

def partition(a, left, right):

    pivotIndex=right
    for i in range(left,right):
        if a[i] > a[pivotIndex]:
            swap(a,i,pivotIndex)


    return pivotIndex

def quicksort(array , left,right):

    if left<right:
        pivotIndex=partition(array,left,right)
        quicksort(array, left, pivotIndex-1)
        quicksort(array, pivotIndex+1, right)

def main():
    quicksort(Array, 0 , len(Array) -1)   
    print (Array )

main()
```