# I am not getting output from the quick sort

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I am not getting output from the quick sort code below:

```py
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length<=1:
        return sequence
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()
        item_greater = []
        item_lower = []
        for item in sequence:
            if item> pivot:
                item_greater.append(item)

            else:
                item_lower.append(item)
                print( quick_sort(item_lower) + [pivot]  + quick_sort(item_greater))
```

Testing the quicksort algorithm:

```
print(quick_sort([91,45,78,124,174,32,75,69,43,15,2,45,19,66]))
```

Comment: You are not actually returning the results. You are simply printing them out. Edit: it also missing a lot of code. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-quicksort/ for reference

Answer (score 1):

Return your values instead of printing them out:

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length<=1:
        return sequence
    else: pivot = sequence.pop()
    item_greter = []
    item_lower = []
    for item in sequence:
        if item > pivot: item_greter.append(item)

        else:
            item_lower.append(item)
            return quick_sort(item_lower) + [pivot]  + quick_sort(item_greter)
            
print(quick_sort([91,45,78,124,174,32,75,69,43,15,2,45,19,66]))
```

Comment: Even this still doesn't work - he's missing a whole bunch of code to begin with.

Comment: Also a pity that this has a worse indentation pattern than the Asker used.

Answer (score 0):

These are the main issues:

1. Your function does not *return* the results, so you'll get `None` back from the recursive call and then the `+ [pivot]` operation will raise an error.
2. Related to the previous point: when the recursive result comes back, it should not be *printed*. Printing should only happen when the final result is ready, i.e. this is a job for the original caller (in the main code).
3. The recursive call should not be made in the loop where you populate the two partitions. It should be made *after* that loop

Not a problem, but the spelling of "greter" is "greater"

Also, you can skip the first `else`, as the `if` block will end in a `return`.

Correction:

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return sequence
    pivot = sequence.pop()
    item_greater = []
    item_lower = []
    for item in sequence:
        if item > pivot: 
            item_greater.append(item)
        else:
            item_lower.append(item)
    return quick_sort(item_lower) + [pivot]  + quick_sort(item_greater)


print(quick_sort([91,45,78,124,174,32,75,69,43,15,2,45,19,66]))
```

### Final remarks

1. It is not nice that this function destroys the input list. If the caller has a reference to that list and inspects it after the call, it will lack one element. This is due to the first `pop` that is executed on it:

   ```
   lst = [91,45,78,124,174,32,75,69,43,15,2,45,19,66]
   print(quick_sort(lst))
   print(lst)  # misses the last element and is not sorted
   ```
2. Quick sort is intended to be an *in-place* sorting algorithm, so you should not need to create new lists (`item_greater` and `item_greater`). Instead these partitions should be formed by *swapping* values in the input list. There should be no `[]` (new empty list) or `+` (list concatenation) in such an implementation.

Correct versions of in-place quick sort algorithms are readily available. There are many variants possible, depending on the pivot selection. Also on this site there are several Q&A on the topic. See for instance:

- [In-place QuickSort in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773516/in-place-quicksort-in-python)
- [inplace quick sort implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148093/inplace-quick-sort-implementation)
- [How to implement quick sort when middle element is the pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724771/python-how-to-implement-quick-sort-when-middle-element-is-the-pivot)
- [Python Quicksort implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225679/python-quicksort-implementation)